# Triangulations dual to braided graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Suppose I have a 3-manifold $M$, and I write down a triangulation $T$ of $M$. Then I can also create a graph $G$ dual to this triangulation, with a node of the graph for every tetrahedron of $T$, and an edge between two nodes in $G$ for every triangular face shared by two tetrahedra in $T$. If I require that the connections of the edges in $G$ have fixed locations on the nodes, then I can define moves acting on the nodes and edges of $G$ which are equivalent to the Pachner moves on $T$. From this, I can find new graphs $G'$ which are each dual to a new triangulation $T'$ of a manifold homeomorphic to $M$.

My questions relate to the extent you can go in the other direction -- from a 4-valent graph to a triangulation of a manifold. Specifically, suppose I have a graph with all nodes having four edges embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so I can have at least some of the edges be part of non-trivial braids.

1. Are there any such braided graphs that correspond to the triangulation of a 3-manifold?
2. If so, what are the restrictions on the braids that allow the duality to work both ways?
3. This question is vaguer, but I am also curious about what exactly "fails" for the braided graphs that do not correspond to a 3-manifold triangulation? In other words, what obstruction due to the braid is preventing the formation of the dual triangulation from a braided 4-valent graph?

Any input or references to these equations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer as such, but just some ideas on where to go with this. Along with my co-authors, I have looked at a very similar problem. We took the dual graph and determined exactly how to "flesh it out" so that it fully encoded the information on a particular triangulation. That is, there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between triangulations and the graph setting that we devised.

Just with the wording, I tend to use arc to mean 'edge of the dual graph' and node to mean 'vertex of the dual graph' to make things a bit clearer when reading.

In the new setting, we replace each arc of the dual graph with a "triple arc" such that each individual arc represents two edges (of distinct tetrahedron faces) which are identified in the triangulation. Then various constraints (such as the 3-manifold constraints) can be converted into this new setting.

The paper is up on arXiv at http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2169 if you want to read further.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply; I had actually come across your paper about the time I wrote this question! I'll have to go back to it and think about the issue some more...